# pandas data frame headers are shifted over when perfoming csv read

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to read data from a csv file into a pandas data frame but the headers are shifting over two columns when read into data frame.

I think it has to do with there being two blank rows after the header, but I'm not sure. It seems to be reading in the first two columns as row titles/indexes.

CSV Format:

```
VendorID,lpep_pickup_datetime,Lpep_dropoff_datetime,Store_and_fwd_flag,RateCodeID,Pickup_longitude,Pickup_latitude,Dropoff_longitude,Dropoff_latitude,Passenger_count,Trip_distance,Fare_amount,Extra,MTA_tax,Tip_amount,Tolls_amount,Ehail_fee,Total_amount,Payment_type,Trip_type 


2,2014-04-01 00:00:00,2014-04-01 14:24:20,N,1,0,0,0,0,1,7.45,23,0,0.5,0,0,,23.5,2,1,,
2,2014-04-01 00:00:00,2014-04-01 17:21:33,N,1,0,0,-73.987663269042969,40.780872344970703,1,8.95,31,1,0.5,0,0,,32.5,2,1,,
```

Data Frame Format:

```
                                   VendorID lpep_pickup_datetime  \
2 2014-04-01 00:00:00  2014-04-01 14:24:20                    N   
  2014-04-01 00:00:00  2014-04-01 17:21:33                    N   
  2014-04-01 00:00:00  2014-04-01 15:06:18                    N   
  2014-04-01 00:00:00  2014-04-01 08:09:27                    N   
  2014-04-01 00:00:00  2014-04-01 16:15:13                    N   

                       Lpep_dropoff_datetime  Store_and_fwd_flag  RateCodeID  \
2 2014-04-01 00:00:00                      1                   0           0   
  2014-04-01 00:00:00                      1                   0           0   
  2014-04-01 00:00:00                      1                   0           0   
  2014-04-01 00:00:00                      1                   0           0   
  2014-04-01 00:00:00                      1                   0           0
```

Code Below:

```
file ='green_tripdata_2014-04.csv'
df4 = pd.read_csv(file)
print(df4.head(5))
```

I just need it to read into the data frame with the headers in the correct location.

Comment: Is that *exactly* your format?  That is, your data file doesn't have any commas?

Comment: No, its in a csv file, so there are commas I believe... just been looking at it via excel to see if the headers were originally formatted in the wrong place.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to copy and paste some of the csv file to the question? Please help by providing more information.

Comment: Is that any more helpful? Just updated the question to include what the file looks like when opened in the command line.

Comment: @BenPrice: much more helpful, because now we can copy and paste to see the same thing you're seeing. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your csv data does look strange - you have 20 column headers, but 22 entries in the first line with data.

Assuming this is only a copy-paste error*, you can try the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=[1,2], index_col=False)
```

`skiprows` will skip the two empty rows, and `index_col` might mitigate the effect of data being interpreted as index columns.

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.read_csv.html for all options to the csv parser.

#### Edit:

*: If your data look exactly as you posted, then your csv is malformed. You have two more data columns (see the last two commas `,,`).

When you delete both commas, the parser works fine.

Another option is to specify the columns to be used:

```
pd.read_csv("file.csv", skiprows=[1,2], usecols=np.arange(20))
```

Here, `np.arange(20)` tells the parser to only parse columns 1-20, that is, the columns that have a valid header (in your first line).

Comment: thats giving me:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: please have a look at my edit. Your csv data seems to be malformed.

Comment: thanks! if thats the case, then the data is malformed... however I have quite a few files, each with about 6M lines of code... do you know if there is there a way to delete those double commas/extra columns as I read it into pandas?